# i'm getting this error when i use gmfitdist Ill-conditioned covariance created at iteration 1

Tags: matlab, k-means, gaussian

i have data set and perform gmfitdist function on it but get ill condition error always.I change the data set many time but getting same error

```
 mycsv = csvread('channel 6.csv',0,1);
 X=mycsv(2000:8000,204:206);
 k=3;
 value2(:,:,3)=cat(3,[1 0 0;0 1 0 ;0 0 1]);
 value3=ones(1,k)/k;
 for j=1:10
 [Ind,c(:,:,j)] = kmeans(X,k);
 end
 value1=c(:,:,3);
 s = struct('mu',value1,'Sigma',value2,'Prob',value3);
 GMM=fitgmdist(X,k,'Start',s) ;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question in the form of a [mcve]